# Count how many reviews a post has - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I need to count how many reviews a post has. How would I go about doing that?

Here is my Listing.php Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Listing extends Model
{

    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Review');
    }

}
```

Here is my Review.php model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Review extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['stars','name','comment'];

    public function listing()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Listing');
    }
}
```

Here is my method that I'am trying to count in controller

```
 public function mostReviews(Request $request) {

        $listings = Review::orderBy('-- most reviews here --')->take(10)->get();

        $headline = 'Most Reviewed Listings';

        return view('pages.listings', compact('listings', 'headline'));

    }
```

Here is my review table:

[image: Review table for listing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
public function mostReviews() {

  $reviews = DB::table('reviews')
      ->select(DB::raw('AVG(stars) as review_score, listing_id'))
      ->groupBy('listing_id')
      ->orderBy('review_score', 'desc')
      ->limit(10)
      ->get();

  foreach($reviews as $key => $review) {
    $reviews[$key] = Listing::find($review->listing_id);
  }

  return view('listings.most-reviews', [
    'listings' => $reviews
  ]);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it but the query below (using the query builder) should give you what you want - 10 listings with the most reviews. Additionally `average_stars` column should return average stars rate. You can easily modify the query to get 10 highest rated listings by changing `orderBy` to `average_stars`.

```
$listings = \DB::table('reviews AS r')
   ->select([
     'r.listing_id',
     \DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS no_of_reviews'),
     \DB::raw('AVG(r.stars) AS average_stars'),
     'l.*'])
   ->join('listings AS l', 'l.id', '=', 'r.listing_id')
   ->limit(10)
   ->orderBy('no_of_reviews', 'DESC')
   ->groupBy('listing_id')
   ->get();
```

Please note version up to version 5.2 of Laravel this will return array of `stdObject`. You can easily access those in your blade template in a similar way as Eloquent Collection.

```
@foreach($listings as $listing)
<tr>
   <td>{{ $listing->id }}</td>
   <td>{{ $listing->title }}</td>
   <td>{{ $listing->no_of_reviews }}</td>
   <td>{{ floor($listing->average_stars) }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
$listing = Listing::with('reviews')->orderByRaw(function($listing)
{
    return $listing->review->count();
}, desc)->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: This might work, but I need to sort each post by most reviews, from highest to lowest. Right now is not showing anything.

Comment: try adding `->get()` after `take(10)`

Comment: its giving me this error: **strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given**

Comment: Take a look at my edited on top, this gives me a count off all rieviews with 3 stars, But I just need to find out the higest reviews

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$review = Review::orderBy('-- most reviews here --');
$reviewCount = $review->count();
$listings=$review->take(10)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

in your listing model:

```
  public function countReview() { 
  return count($this->reviews); 
  }
```

in your views :

```
 {{$listing->countReview()}}
```

maybe in controller you can write somthing like :

```
 public function mostReviews() { 
  Review::orderBy('listing', 'desc')->blahblah; // or 'asc'
 }
```

Comment: where is $this->products coming from?

Comment: put that code in your listing model, i made custom function to count the review. Sorry I'm forget to chenge it, I'm copying the code from my project

Comment: I'm using the code in my current project and it works